# About verbose methods in command line for windows and phrasing through things

Tags: batch-file, cmd

```
:: preserve environment variable settings
setlocal
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:: check to see if switches are passed
set arg=%1
set verbose=NO
if "%arg:~,1%" == "/" ( 
if /i "%arg%" == "/v" (
  set verbose=YES
  echo verbose option is !verbose!
  shift /1
) else if "%arg%" == "/?" (
  :: display a usage message for a /? switch
  echo.
  echo Usage: %0 [/?] [servername] ...
  echo This batch file displays server
  echo statistics for each passed server name.
  exit /b 1
```

)

```
  if "%1" == "" (
  set /p servers="Please input the server names: "
)  else  (
 set servers=%*
)
:: process each server name
for %%s in (%servers%) do call :srvDetails %%s
:: restore environment variable settings
endlocal
goto :EOF

:: subroutine to check the server details
:srvDetails
echo.
:: only display is verbose is set
if "%verbose%" == "YES" echo Checking server details for %1
nslookup %1
pause
exit /b
```

I wrote this code and i am trying to when someone inputs like subtest.bat /v cod.edu meaning that put a /v and a server to check the shift command will then shift it over and not run it through the nslookup while still enabling the verbose to ON. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Suppose to say then shift**

Comment: I think it's not clear what exactly you want to achieve and what happens now instead...

Answer (score 1):

`set servers=%*` is your problem.  When you do `shift`, `%*` remains unchanged, so you need to manually remove the flag:

```
set "servers=%*"
[...]
if "%1"=="/v" (
    [...]
    set "servers=!servers:~3!"
)
```